# converting graphics files from webP to gif

Tags: graphics, gif, webp

I have downloaded a number of video clips they are in a format called .webp.  How do I convert them to .gif? A chat room I use frequently only allows .gif and .jpeg files.

I've done something like this before but it was ages ago and I can't remember what to do.

Comment: On 20.04 imagemagick had no issues converting a simple webp image to gif. Simple command line I used was `convert image.webp test.gif`. Does this work on your system? If this does not work straight up try the following: `sudo apt-get install webp` before repeating the `convert....` command again...

Comment: my system doesn't have the `convert` command. i've tried `sudo apt install convert` and get the reply `package convert does not exist` what package is convert in?

Comment: It should be part of the imagemagick package...

Comment: yes convert don't wotk for gif animations i need to use webpmux to remove each frame and then recontruct as a gif animation but i struggle wit h the commands

Comment: `convert` does not support webp, even with the webp package.

Comment: does anyone know how to use webpmux. i have the man page, but there is something i'm missing when trying to extract a frame from an animation

Comment: convert DOES support webp, but you need to download and compile the latest version, with libwebp-dev package installed.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by modifying a script by Sean Mahan that appears to have been intended for Arch Linux I simply quoted the variables (otherwise it failed under Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS). Here's the Ubuntu script I used. This could be further modified to include checking to insure all dependencies are installed (and optionally installing them if not).

```
#!/bin/bash

DELAY="${DELAY:-10}"
LOOP="${LOOP:-0}"
r=`realpath "$1"`
d=`dirname "$r"`
pushd "$d" > /dev/null
f=`basename "$r"`
n=`webpinfo -summary "$f" | grep frames | sed -e 's/.* \([0-9]*\)$/\1/'`
dur=`webpinfo -summary "$f" | grep Duration | head -1 |  sed -e 's/.* \([0-9]*\)$/\1/'`

if (( "$dur" > 0 )); then
    DELAY = "$dur"
fi

pfx=`echo -n $f | sed -e 's/^\(.*\).webp$/\1/'`
if [ -z "$pfx" ]; then
    pfx="$f"
fi

echo "converting "$n" frames from "$f" 
working dir "$d"
file stem "$pfx""

for i in $(seq -f "%05g" 1 "$n")
do
    webpmux -get frame "$i" "$f" -o "$pfx"."$i".webp
    dwebp "$pfx"."$i".webp -o "$pfx"."$i".png
done

convert "$pfx".*.png -delay "$DELAY" -loop "$LOOP" "$pfx".gif
rm "$pfx".[0-9]*.png "$pfx".[0-9]*.webp
popd > /dev/null
exit
```

**Solution dependencies:**

1. webp package
   2.imagemagick package
   3.and of course bash

Answer (score 1):

Python batch convert utility. Based on above contribution.

Requires creating a global `webp-to-gif` executable with [Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek)'s Sean Mahan code...

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
print( "####################################################" )
print( "Uses webp-to-gif to convert multiple..." )
print( "Converts all found if no regex provided             " )
print( "args: [group regex: optional] [path: optional]      " )
print( "                                                    " )
print( "####################################################" )

import sys, os, fnmatch, itertools
import re

args = [x.replace('\\', '') for x in list(sys.argv)];  args.pop(0)
if len(args) == 1: args = args[0].split(' ')


print()
print()
print( "---------------------------------" )
print( "           Begin...              " )
print( "---------------------------------" )
print()
print()

regex = r'(.*)\.webp'
path = '.'
if len(args):
    regex = args[0]
    if len(args)>1:
        path = args[1]

os.chdir(path)
nn = 0
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    m = re.match(regex, f)
    if m:
        fn, e = os.path.splitext(f)
        os.system('webp-to-gif %s %s' % (f, '%s.gif' % (fn))) 
        print( '- Done for "%s"' % f )
        nn += 1

print()
print()
print( '---------------------------------' )
print( "%i matched" % nn )
print() 
print()
print( "---------------------------------" )
print( "             Done                " ) 
print( "---------------------------------" )
print() 
print()
```